# Dynamically adding XElements to XAttribute using C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<servers>  
  <server serverid="server1" asset="Sample" >
    <port portid ="port1" asset="Sample"  ></port>  
    <port portid ="port2" asset="Sample"  ></port>      
  </server>

  <server serverid="server2" asset="Sample" >
    <port portid ="port1" asset="Sample"  ></port> 
    <port portid ="port2" asset="Sample"  ></port>    
    <port portid ="port3" asset="Sample"  ></port>
    <port portid ="port4" asset="Sample"  ></port>        
  </server>
<server serverid="server1" asset="Sample" >
    <port portid ="port1" asset="Sample"  ></port> 
    <port portid ="port2" asset="Sample"  ></port>    
    <port portid ="port3" asset="Sample"  ></port>   
  </server>

</servers>
```

I am trying to add Server XElements and port XElements to the existing XML DOC. I tried by using for & forEach to add port Xelements to server Xelement. The trick here is the count of port XElemnts vary from server to server. Please help me out of this.
The following is the sample code, I have tried.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\sample.xml");
             var server = new XElement("server",
                 new XAttribute("serverid", ServerId),
                 new XAttribute("name", ServerName),
                 (foreach(var sample in test)
                 {
                 new XElement("port",
                     new XAttribute("asset", PortName),
                     new XAttribute("portid", PortId));
                 });
```

Comment: Try to get `port Count` for every server and do the loop for `port count` to add new `port` elements .\

Answer (score 2):

It's strange that you are not using `sample` variable in a loop. But if you want to add new `port` element for each item in `test` collection, then you should project each item to `XElement` and return collection of these elements:

```
 var fileName = @"C:\sample.xml";
 var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

 var server = 
     new XElement("server",
         new XAttribute("serverid", ServerId),
         new XAttribute("name", ServerName),
             test.Select(sample =>
                 new XElement("port",
                     new XAttribute("asset", PortName),
                     new XAttribute("portid", PortId)
                 ))
         );
```

Keep in mind, that `foreach` loop does not return anything. But you need to provide value to server element you are creating.

```
 xdoc.Root.Add(server);
 xdoc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: In the sample code PortName & PortId are array variables,not able to assign array index for each "test" iterate.